# Exception StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC

Tags: java, file, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream

I want to serialize a same object on file, each time when i run a program. This is a simple algorithm to explain my problem.

In the begening i store a `String` on `writer`. in the last i read a file.
The goal of this program is if i run my program X time, i store and i print on screen X time my object.

```
class ReadFile {

    static ObjectOutputStream writer = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        writer = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("trace", true));
        store("String");

        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }

        open("file.tmp");

    }

    static public void store(String chaine) {
        if (writer == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            writer.writeObject(chaine);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }

    static public void open(String file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        ObjectInputStream objs;
        try {

            objs = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Object obj = objs.readObject();
                    str.append(obj.toString());
                }
            } catch (EOFException ex) {
            }
            objs.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

When i run this program i have this error :

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1355)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at ReadFile.open(ReadFile.java:47)
        at ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:35)
```

What can i do please ?

Comment: Rather than catching exceptions and just discarding them, you should inspect them and see if they contain anything useful that may point to the problem. Also, which is line 35 of this code?

Comment: Line 35 is : `open("file.tmp");`

Comment: Why not read all the objects into a list first and then add the object that you want to append and then write back to the file. I know it's time consuming and over doing, but it worked in my case. Look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182240/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-type-code-ac) post you cannot append to a ObjectOutputStream, which you are trying to do by opening the underlying FileOutputStream in append mode. There is a solution mentioned on that post such that you create an AppendableObjectOutputStream , or you could just open the FileOutputStream without appending.