# Serialization - Why readObject doesn't reads whole file?

Tags: java, list, casting, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm a beginner with Java and I meet a problem with a read/write to text file.

The process :

- read and display the text file : System.out.println(garage);
- add a first car : garage.addVoiture(lag1);
- add a second car : garage.addVoiture(A300B_2);

Here is main.java :

```
import fr.ocr.vehicule2.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Garage garage = new Garage();
     System.out.println(garage);

     Vehicule lag1 = new Lagouna();
     lag1.setMoteur(new MoteurEssence("150 Chevaux", 10256d));
     lag1.addOption(new GPS());
     lag1.addOption(new SiegeChauffant());
     lag1.addOption(new VitreElectrique());
     garage.addVoiture(lag1);

     Vehicule A300B_2 = new A300B();
     A300B_2.setMoteur(new MoteurElectrique("1500 W", 1234d));
     A300B_2.addOption(new Climatisation());
     A300B_2.addOption(new BarreDeToit());
     A300B_2.addOption(new SiegeChauffant());
     garage.addVoiture(A300B_2);
}
```

and here is garage.java

```
package fr.ocr.vehicule2;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Garage {

  private List<Vehicule> voitures = new ArrayList<Vehicule>();;
  ObjectInputStream ois;
  ObjectOutputStream oos;

  public Garage(){
  }

  public String toString() {
    System.out.println("DEBUG start toString");

    String str = "";
    // Vérification de l'existence du fichier de sauvegarde
    if(Files.notExists(Paths.get("garage.txt"))) str += "Aucune voiture sauvegardée !\n";

    str += "*************************\n" 
       + "* Garage OpenClassrooms *\n"
       + "*************************\n";

    // Lecture du fichier texte
    if(Files.exists(Paths.get("garage.txt"))) {
      try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("garage.txt"))));
          str += ((Vehicule)ois.readObject()).toString();
        ois.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (EOFException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 
    }
    System.out.println("DEBUG end toString");
    return str;
  }

  public void addVoiture(Vehicule voit) {

    System.out.println("DEBUG start addVoiture" + voit);

    voitures.add(voit);

    // écriture du fichier texte
    try {
      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
          new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(
              new File("garage.txt"))));

//      for(Vehicule V:voitures){
//              oos.writeObject(V);
//          }
      oos.writeObject(voit);
      oos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    System.out.println("DEBUG end addVoiture");
  }
}
```

First execution of main.java, (the text file doesn't exists) I get in console :

- Aucune voiture sauvegardée !
- ---
- - Garage OpenClassrooms *
- ---
- start addVoiture
- end addVoiture
- start addVoiture
- end addVoiture

That's what I want to show in console for first launch.

But second execution of main.java, (the text file exists),  I get in console :

- DEBUG start toString
- DEBUG end toString
- ---
- - Garage OpenClassrooms *
- ---
- - Voiture PIGEOT : Lagouna Moteur ELECTRIQUE 1500 W (1234.0) [Climatisation (347.3€), Barre de toit (29.9€), Siège chauffant (562.9€)] d'une valeur totale de 2174.1€
- DEBUG start addVoiture+ Voiture RENO : Lagouna Moteur ESSENCE 150 Chevaux (10256.0) [GPS (113.5€), Siège chauffant (562.9€), Vitres electrique  (212.35€)] d'une valeur totale de 11144.75€
- DEBUG end addVoiture
- DEBUG start addVoiture+ Voiture PIGEOT : Lagouna Moteur ELECTRIQUE 1500 W (1234.0) [Climatisation (347.3€), Barre de toit (29.9€), Siège chauffant (562.9€)] d'une valeur totale de 2174.1€
- DEBUG end addVoiture
  Only the second car (+ Voiture PIGEOT) is shown in console.

The result I want is both of them, ordered the same way I added them :

- ---

  _ * Garage OpenClassrooms *
  _ *************************
- - Voiture RENO : Lagouna Moteur ESSENCE 150 Chevaux (10256.0) [GPS (113.5€), Siège chauffant (562.9€), Vitres electrique  (212.35€)] d'une valeur totale de 11144.75€
- - Voiture PIGEOT : Lagouna Moteur ELECTRIQUE 1500 W (1234.0) [Climatisation (347.3€), Barre de toit (29.9€), Siège chauffant (562.9€)] d'une valeur totale de 2174.1€

I don't find the solution to this issue, 
Is it because I don't write correctly both cars : oos.writeObject(voit);
or because I don't read it correctly : str += ((Vehicule)ois.readObject()).toString(); ?

I've searched a lot even on stackoverflow but the code seems to be correct. So it may be a problem with the way I write then read the file ?

Thanks a lot if someone can help, I'm spending lots of time but turn around.

---

Added after @Kevin Anderson informations :

---

Thanks a lot again for help!

I changed readObject with your script but I still get only the last car added.

I've also seen this post ([java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182240/java-io-streamcorruptedexception-invalid-type-code-ac/3182290#3182290)) and wasn't able to solve it. So I changed the way I writeObject (stopped appending objects to ObjectOutputStream) and get an almost good result.

Now my ultime issue is with "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List" on readObject().

I think (not sure ?) that it's just an IDE information so I suppose it would be better to do the correct way, so I would like to avoid using (@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")) over (public String toString() {) and do it the best way but I was unable to apply any of all solutions I found on Stackoverflow.

If you have an idea, that would be really perfect !

Here is new garage.java :

```
public class Garage {

  private List<Vehicule> voitures = new ArrayList<Vehicule>();
  private ObjectInputStream ois;
  protected static ObjectOutputStream oos;

  public Garage(){}

  public String toString() {

    String str = "";

    // Vérification de l'existence du fichier de sauvegarde
    if(Files.notExists(Paths.get("garage.txt"))) {
      str += "Aucune voiture sauvegardée !\n";
    }

    str += "*************************\n" 
       + "* Garage OpenClassrooms *\n"
       + "*************************\n";

    // Lecture du fichier texte
    if(Files.exists(Paths.get("garage.txt"))) {
      try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("garage.txt"))));

        // garage loading during instanciation :
              // Information Eclipse : 
              // Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<Vehicule>
              this.voitures = (List<Vehicule>)ois.readObject();

        // Affichage des voitures enregistrées dans le fichier texte
        for(Vehicule V : this.voitures){
          str += V;
        }


              // To avoid "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<Vehicule>" :
        // those 2 solutions show identical information "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List<Vehicule>"

        // First tried solution :
        // this.voitures = new new ArrayList<Vehicule>((List<Vehicule>)ois.readObject()); 

              // Second tried solution :
//              if(ois.readObject() instanceof List<?>){
//                  List<?> list = (ArrayList<?>)ois.readObject();
//                  for(Object e : list){
//                     if(e instanceof Vehicule){
//                       this.voitures = (List<Vehicule>)e;
//                     }
//                  }
//              }


        ois.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (EOFException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 
    }
    return str;
  }

  public void addVoiture(Vehicule voit) {

    voitures.add(voit);

    // écriture du fichier texte
    try {
      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
          new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(
              new File("garage.txt"))));

      // Enregistrement detoutes les voitures dans le fichier texte
      oos.writeObject(voitures);

      oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
}
```

---

Added solution for Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List

---

Thanks to this post : [Type safety: Unchecked cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262367/type-safety-unchecked-cast/13387897)

The text file contains a List object 
    
and when I launch Garage() I needed to  add this List object to the existing List voitures.

Eclipse was showing :
    Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List

I could use : @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to my method, but it looks better to do this way so I don't ignore any warning :

```
    List<?> list = (List<?>) ois.readObject();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      this.voitures.add((Vehicule) list.get(i)); // instanciation
      str += (Vehicule) list.get(i);// Added to console message
    }
```

Hope it helps, sorry for my beginner mistakes ^^, and thanks to all for help !

Comment: You keep writing `the text file exists`, but `ObjectOutputStream` writes binary, not text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call `addVoiture`, you're overwriting the data file, not adding onto it. Change  your file-opening code to

```
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
      new BufferedOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(
          new File("garage.txt"), true)));
```

That extra arg `true` on `new FileOutputStream` opens an existing file for appending instead of creating a new empty file every time.  See the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.lang.String-boolean-)

Also, since you're writing multiple `Vehicule` objects to your file, you have to execute multiple `readObject` calls to read all of them back again.  The reason you only ever see one car is because you only call `readObject` one time.  You need to keep calling `readObject` in a loop until you get an `EOFException`:

```
try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("garage.txt"))));
        for(;;){
            try {
               str += ((Vehicule)ois.readObject()).toString();
            } catch (EOFException eofe) {
               break;
            }
        }
        ois.close();
      }
} catch ....
```

With this change, you shouldn't need to catch `EOFException` with the outer `try` block anymore because the inner `try` now handles it.

Comment: Thanks to all for overwriting information. But I've added "true" parameter to FileOutputStream for appending, and (str += ((Vehicule)ois.readObject()).toString();) still only returns the last car added  (Voiture PIGEOT : Lagouna Moteur ELECTRIQUE). I suppose that it means the file only contains last car added. There is certainly another problem :/ ?

Comment: Thanks again, I've updated the code but finally changed the way I writeObject and get another information. see updated post.

Comment: It's ok I found a way to avoid warning during List cast.

Comment: You can’t append to an object output stream like this. Answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The name tells you what you need to do: *read* an **object**.

It is not named *read* **File**.

In other words: when you use Object streams, your code defines which objects get written in which order. And then, on the other side, similar code has to *read* these objects in the very same order.

This is all there is to this.

And your current code **overwrites** the existing file. When you want to "preserve" the file content - then you first have to read in the objects that were stored previously.