# Serialize KeyguardLock

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am writing an android application and I need to have two classes use the same KeyguardLock object but I am experiencing extreme difficulty in sharing (via serialization) that object.  I have tried using the [serialization stackoverflow example link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118751/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-android) but that didn't work at all.  I get a "not serializable" IO exception trying to save the object.   I have also tried using JSONObject.

Any ideas?  Has anyone run into a similar problem?

Comment: Also worth noting that I have to use the same object as using keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) twice causes issues.  See [android issue 14246](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14246)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to serialize it? A object can only be serialize if it implements `Serializable` which `KeyguardLock` doesn't.

If you're trying to pass it around Activities, either create a custom `Application` object and store it there. Or use a `public static` variable  in a class and access it via that. The static variable is probably the better option for this.

Comment: Never mind, your solution works.  I think I need to revamp my knowledge of public static as I didn't know it behaved in that manor.  I'll leave the code up below as an example to other people with a similar problem.