# Saving and Retrieving ArrayLists

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm terribly new to Android, and what I want to do, is to save 2 arraylists permanently. The context is as follows: The user will select an option from a listview, and the app will load the 2 arraylists with their corresponding data, according to which option he chooses. I've explored quite a few options, such as saving with SharedPreferences, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement the methods discussed. Will provide code if required!

Comment: Some code *would* be nice.

Comment: @JulesMazur why do you need code for hat question?

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) provides information about all storages, usable in your context. Code examples are provided as well.

I don't think that SharedPreferences are what you are looking for. I would rather use a database (might be oversized for your use case) or simply save a file to the filesystem (also described in the link).

If you choose the second approach, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118751/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-android) will help you how to serialize your object (class containing both lists)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use java `Serialisation`, which you write into a file.
If the lists are huge (thousans elems) then could write using custom Serialisation by using `DataOutputStream`. This uses less space and is faster, but more work.