# How can I save all my booleans at once in onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android

Is there some way to "capture a snapshot" of the app when calling onSaveInstanceState?

Otherwise I have to save each boolean and keep track on them and try not to forget something, like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (userAvatar != null) {
            outState.putString("userAvatar", userAvatar.toString());
            avatarAlreadyProvided = true;
        }
        if (sexIsOK) {
            outState.putBoolean("sexIsOK", true);
        }
        if (passwordIsOk) {
            outState.putBoolean("passwordIsOk", true);          
        }
        if (passwordAgainIsOk) {
            outState.putBoolean("passwordAgainIsOk", true);         
        }
        if (passwordsMatch) {
            outState.putBoolean("passwordsMatch", true);                
        }
        if (userHasProvidedOwnPhoto != false) {
            outState.putBoolean("userHasProvidedOwnPhoto", true);
            outState.putBoolean("avatarAlreadyProvided", true);
        }
        if (mImageBitmap != null) {
            outState.putParcelable("mImageBitmap", mImageBitmap);
            avatarAlreadyProvided = true;
        }
        if (usernameIsOk) {
            outState.putBoolean("usernameIsOk", true);          
        }
        if (allSignupFieldsProperlyFilled) {
            outState.putBoolean("allSignupFieldsProperlyFilled", true);         
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(outState);
        userHasProvidedOwnPhoto = outState.getBoolean("userHasProvidedOwnPhoto");
        avatarAlreadyProvided = outState.getBoolean("avatarAlreadyProvided");
        mImageBitmap = outState.getParcelable("mImageBitmap");
        userAvatar = outState.getString("userAvatar");
        iUserAvatar.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        allSignupFieldsProperlyFilled = outState.getBoolean("allSignupFieldsProperlyFilled");
        usernameIsOk = outState.getBoolean("usernameIsOk");
        passwordsMatch = outState.getBoolean("passwordsMatch");
        passwordAgainIsOk = outState.getBoolean("passwordAgainIsOk");
        passwordIsOk = outState.getBoolean("passwordIsOk");
        sexIsOK = outState.getBoolean("sexIsOK");


    }
```

I always forget something and I mess it up. There has to be some other way....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your variables up into a Java class and use serialization. You can use Gson for Json serialisation.

[How do I serialize an object and save it to a file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118751/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-android)

Comment: well, again I have to get all my variables? can you give me an example?

Comment: Even if you have a hundred variables in your Java object serialization reduces the saving and loading to a few lines. Start by adding a new class to your project and moving all the variables into it. Then look at the other answer I linked to.

Comment: so what do I do in onSaveInstanceState? I serialize the variables object?