# Android, solution/library to store http request waiting for web connection

Tags: android

I have an app that must save form inputs instead of send if there is no web connection.

And send them once the phone is connected.

I was wondering if there is already some code made to handle the feature.

Otherwise, the solution would be to save in sharedpreferences something like :

```
1_inputA
1_inputB
2_inputA
2_inputB
```

Do you have any other idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

1. Create the `Service` which will be run in background all the time.
2. Create the `ArrayList` with `Serealizable` objects, every objects hold info about one request which you want to send.
3. In `Service` create the the `AlarmManager` which will checks every N minutes/seconds if there is internet connection.
4. After user enter data to input form, you also check is there is internet connection. If no, you just add new object to `ArrayList` and searelize (write to disk) the `ArrayList`.
5. If there is a connection you desearelize (read from the disk ArrayList), add there your last input data and send it to server.
6. Also every N time your `AlarmManager` check if there is interenet connection, it do the same thing as wrote in **5**.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, very interesting, ArrayList Serializable.  Is this good to save ArrayList like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118751/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-android ?

Comment: Yes, it is good way to save it, just don't forget to 'implement serializable' in object which you will store in ArrayList