# What is the best way to storage a custom class in Android?

Tags: android

On my android app I'm using a custom class, that extends from application, to share persistent data between activities and what I want to know is the best way to store that class ? With this I mean; what is the best storage option for my custom class so, if the user reboots or kills the app, I don't lose any information.

Comment: shared prefrences does not clear until and unless you do so. Else database in android is a good option too.

Comment: Shared preferences is the way to go, for storing options http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html They are cleared on uninstall, or if the user manually clears it.

Comment: What I want to store are not user options. Maybe a database is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options:

1. Parse the object to a JSON string and save it in shared prefrences. [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
2. Serialize and save the object. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118751/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-android)
3. Use a SingleTon to make data accessible. [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm)

Comment: The singleton was not what I need but the rest was good info. Thanks :)