# Is there a better way to pre-load items into a database?

Tags: android, sqlite, hashmap, android-sqlite

In my Android app I have a

1. SQLiteHelper class that extends SQLIteOpenHelper, and takes care of things like table-creation and upgrades.
2. SQLiteDatasource class that performs CRUD operations on the SQLiteHelper object.

I want to pre-load one of the tables with certain items so there is something present when the user first uses the app. These items may change so I want to make them modular.

Right now I am doing it this way:

```
public class MyDefaults {
    public static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MY_DEFAULTS;

    static {
        MY_DEFAULTS = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        //All the values below you change to whatever defaults you want
        map.clear();
        map.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_1, "Value 1A");
        map.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_2, "Value 2A");
        map.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_3, "Value 3A");
        MY_DEFAULTS.add(new HashMap<String, String>(map));

        map.clear();
        map.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_1, "Value 1B");
        map.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_2, "Value 2B");
        map.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_3, "Value 3B");
        MY_DEFAULTS.add(new HashMap<String, String>(map));

        map.clear();
        map.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_1, "Value 1C");
        map.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_2, "Value 2C");
        map.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_3, "Value 3C");
        MY_DEFAULTS.add(new HashMap<String, String>(map));

        //and so on
    }

}
```

And then in my SQLiteDatasource class I have a method that performs the insert of these default values:

```
public void preloadDefaults() {
    mDatabase.beginTransaction();

    try {
        for (HashMap<String, String> map : MyDefaults.MY_DEFAULTS) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_1, map.get(SQLiteHelper.KEY_1));
            values.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_2, map.get(SQLiteHelper.KEY_2));
            values.put(SQLiteHelper.KEY_3, map.get(SQLiteHelper.KEY_3));
            mDatabase.insert(SQLiteHelper.SOME_TABLE, null, values);
        }
    }
    finally {
        mDatabase.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Is my way of doing this considered bad practice? Is there a better way to define the "defaults" that get inserted into a table after it gets created? Possibly through XML instead of a static class?

Note: I can't just copy an external DB because I'm actually inserting these fields with some other values created at runtime (the code above is a simplification of what my real code is).

Comment: I'd probably go with a CSV file. Make the input look as much like the storage as possible.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn That's a really interesting idea. However I don't see any CSV readers in the autocomplete. Is there any particular method you'd recommend?

Comment: I also started looking because I might do this in one of my projects. Anybody who has recommendations always mentions [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) but I have no experience with it (yet).

Comment: I used OpenCSV in one of my project, and I had no problem.

Comment: I am new to this Android / open-source stuff -- how would I incorporate OpenCSV into my project?

Comment: That's a whole different question, seemingly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ship an Android application with a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Comment: You can add a csv file in raw  folder, and then access it using a CSVReader. And then you can do everything you whant with those data.

Comment: @Joseph82 Would I need to add CSVReader to my project the same way I'd add OpenCSV?

Comment: @bendaf Maybe it technically is, but the accepted answer has a comment condemning that solution. Your own answer is more direct.

Comment: @bendaf For reasons I didn't get into, I can't just copy an external DB because I'm actually inserting these fields with some other values created at runtime, so right now the CSV approach seems more appropriate

Comment: No @ArukaJ CSVReader is a class, provided from OpenCSV, that you can use for reading the csv file.

Comment: Is OpenCSV not in Maven where I can just add a compile line to the dependencies in the gradle?

Comment: Maybe it is 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3' according to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/2.3 ?

Comment: I guess that worked, I seem to have the CSV functions now

Comment: If you want to know how to parse csv file please look at this link:
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/parse-csv-file-in-android-example-sample-code

Comment: @ArukaJ if you know your data you do not need to include that but my advise is to keep the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803319/3162918) answer also
The SQLiteAssetHelper library makes this task really simple.

It's easy to add as a gradle dependency (but a Jar is also available for Ant/Eclipse), and together with the documentation it can be found at:
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

As explained in documentation:

1. Add the dependency to your module's gradle build file:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
   }
   ```
2. Copy the database into the assets directory, in a subdirectory called `assets/databases`. For instance:
   `assets/databases/my_database.db`

   (Optionally, you may compress the database in a zip file such as `assets/databases/my_database.zip`. This isn't needed, since the APK is compressed as a whole already.)
3. Create a class, for example:

   ```
   public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

       private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my_database.db";
       private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

       public MyDatabase(Context context) {
           super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: what do you mean under "what about?" the asset folder will update also... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can memorize your data, with Serialize Objects. Read here:

[How do I serialize an object and save it to a file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118751/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-android)

Comment: I'm not sure this really addresses my core problem -- and isn't Parcelable much faster than Serializable in Android?

Comment: Yep, but the Parceleable Objects, have a significant amount of boilerplate code and it makes the classes harder to read and maintain