# How to make MCQ test functionality that loads data from server

Tags: android

I am working on learning application. I want to add MCQ test functionality in my app. I want to load data from the server when the test started. and it will not call to the server for each question because it will slow down test process. I want to load all the question when the test starts and a new question will appear only when clicking on next question button. There will be four option in each question so at the end I want to send data to the server to verify the answer. I actually confused in what should I used to save question in internal memory. and then their answer to submit to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Android [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) has an explanatory list of available options for storage that you can leverage. Since you would want to keep this information secure. I suggest you should use one from the list below

1. Internal file storage: Store app-private files on the device file
   system.
2. Databases: Store structured data in a private database.

Although a lot depends on the size of data and other specifics of your use case.

Based on the discussion in the comments. Here is a cool [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33896724/1069073) to the same, i.e serialize/deserialize the objects.

Comment: can i  use objects to store this questions and their options?

Comment: Yes, you can serialize the object(s) into files. if you prefer.

Comment: Let me add a link to the snippet.