# What is the best way to store and access variables in all activities

Tags: java, android

I have an app in which I have more than 450 custom Java objects, and about 200 other variables of strings, int, etc.
I know that these much variables use large RAM of the device, so I want to know the best way for storing and accessing them. Some variables are used in many activities.

Comment: It depends on many things. What they contains, they purpose, how often they are accessed, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely persist them to a a file since they are so many. Doing this you can load the classes in when you need them and not worry about memory

Saving custom class

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
os.writeObject(this);
os.close();
fos.close();
```

Loading custom Class

```
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
SimpleClass simpleClass = (SimpleClass) is.readObject();
is.close();
fis.close();
```

Here´s another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118751/how-do-i-serialize-an-object-and-save-it-to-a-file-in-android) with some cool implementations of this

Answer (score 0):

you can use data base for storing variables in memory but it better to use `Sharedprefrences` to store all variables :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); 
editor.commit();
```

and easilly get the variable :

```
pref.getString("key_name", null);
```

Comment: i use SharedPreferences to save score and progresses , but will it be ideal to save more than 600 variable in it?

Comment: Don't store this much amount of variables in sharedPrefs, every time you access sharedPrefs all of them will be loaded in memory.