# Appending to ObjectOutputStream (writing multiple objects w/o closing stream)

Tags: java, serialization, objectoutputstream

Desclaimer My question is different from two following links

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646272/appending-objects-to-a-binary-file)

```
    public class AppendableObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {
      public AppendableObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
      }

      @Override
      protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {}
}
```

- The problem with above solutions is that they do not support writing multiple objects to appendable stream w/o closing the stream.
- If I open appendable stream, write multiple objects - then at time of reading I can read only first object properly and on trying to read second object, I get EOF exception.
- If I proceed the way like write on object to appendable stream, close stream. Then again open stream, write another object close and so on. This way I am able to read multiple objects properly.

  ```
      fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("abc.dat",true);
       outputBuffer = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
       objectStream = new AppendableObjectOutputStream(outputBuffer);
       BucketUpdate b1 = new BucketUpdate("getAllProducts1",null,"1",null);
       BucketUpdate b2 = new BucketUpdate("getAllProducts2",null,"2",null);
       BucketUpdate b3 = new BucketUpdate("getAllProducts3",null,"3",null);
       objectStream.writeObject(b1);
       objectStream.writeObject(b2);
       objectStream.writeObject(b3);
       objectStream.close();
  ```

Comment: What implementation of `AppendableObjectOutputStream` do you use?

Comment: @justYo have added code for my AppendableObjectOutputStream implementation

Comment: Posted an answer, probably that's the case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling ObjectOutputStream.reset() after writing each object will fix this.

Answer (score 4):

If you check question you [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream), you will see that you have to use `AppendableObjectOutputStream` only to **append** objects to file, if file already contains some objects. For empty file you have to use ordinary `ObjectOutputStream` because the header should be written to the beginning in this case.

Comment: That sounds like a plausible solution, i would give it a try