# Serialization/deserialization ClassCastException: x cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectStreamClass

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Using Java's native serialization, I'm intermittently seeing ClassCastExceptions

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: myCompany.MyClass$MembershipServiceMethod cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectStreamClass
```

or (less frequently)

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectStreamClass
```

when I deserialize objects of a particular immutable class. That is to say, the exception is always thrown for particular serialized representations, but most objects can be successfully serialized and deserialized.

```
public final class ServiceInteractionImpl implements ServiceInteraction, Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final InteractionSource source;
private final long startTime;
private final InteractionType type;
private final ServiceMethod method;
private final long duration;
private final String accompanyingMessage;

public ServiceInteractionImpl(final ServiceMethod method,
                                  final InteractionSource source,
                                  final InteractionType type,
                                  final long startTime,
                                  final long duration,
                                  final String accompanyingMessage) {
            this.source = source;
            this.startTime = startTime;
            this.duration = duration;
            this.type = type;
            this.method = method;
            this.accompanyingMessage = accompanyingMessage;
    }

    ...

    getters and canonical methods
}
```

where InteractionSource, InteractionType and ServiceMethod are enums. 
I can't replicate this in my local environment running junit tests that serialize and deserialize millions of objects.

Here is the writing code

```
    fileLock.lock();
    try {
        final File recordFile = new File(recordFileName);
        boolean appendToFile = false;

        if (recordFile.exists()) {
            appendToFile = true;
        }

        final OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(recordFileName, true);
        final OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

        ObjectOutput output;
        if (appendToFile) {
            output = new AppendableObjectOutputStream(buffer);
        } else {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
        }

        int localSerializedInteractionsCount = 0;

        try {
            for (final ServiceInteraction interaction : tempCollection) {
                output.writeObject(interaction);
                output.flush();
                localSerializedInteractionsCount++;
                rollBackCollection.remove(interaction);
            }
        } finally {
            output.close();
            serializedInteractionCount += localSerializedInteractionsCount;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("could not write to file", e);
        //some roll-back code
    } finally {
        fileLock.unlock();
    }
```

see [Appending to an ObjectOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream) for the AppendableObjectOutputStream

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Reading between the lines here, I see two different run time environments - it fails in one, but runs in another.  Details on diffs between environments?

Comment: @RichardSitze Just one runtime, but I've moved on from this issue and couldn't usefully participate in a discussion about it now.

Answer (score 0):

If the class definition changed without updating serialVersionUID then its possible these errors are from stale object instances based on the old class definition.