# ClassCastException when Appending Object OutputStream

Tags: java, serialization, classcastexception, java-io

I have been trying to do a little project that needs an appendable ObjectOutputStream.
I have gone through a couple of solutions and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream) It seemed to solve my problem at first. But on further development of my project i started getting unexpected exceptions.
The following are my classes.

```
public class PPAccount implements Serializable
{
    private Profile profile;
    private String email;
    private float accountBal;
    private boolean isActivated;
    private String activationCode;
    private ArrayList<Transaction> transactions;

    //a few functions   
}
public class PPRestrictedAccount extends PPAccount {
    private String parentEmail;
    private float withdrawLimit;

        //a few functions
}
public class PPBusinessAccount extends PPAccount {
    private ArrayList <PPRestrictedAccount> accountOperators;

        //a few functions
}
public class PPStudentAccount extends PPAccount {
    private String parentEmail;

        //a few functions
}
```

What i have observed is, using the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream) i have overridden the ObjectOutputStream and used it while i am appending the objects to the file. But what happens is if i write:

`PPBusinessAccount` first, repeat any number of times... then write `PPAccount` all is well.
`PPAccount` first, repeat.... then write `PPBusinessAccount` then write `PPAccount`, it writes well but while reading i get a `ClassCastException`.

I am tried reading the Objects and storing them directly in an instance of `Object` class to avoid the class cast but still `readObject()` throws `ClassCastException`.

I tried best to describe my scenario, tell if you don't get anything. Why is this happening?? has it got something to do with the header that it is writing for this first time?? Along the lines of Base class header cannot support child class?? What's the turn around?

I am doing the cast like this:

```
Object o = ois.readObject();        //Surprisingly exception is raised here (line:50 in DataStore)
PPAccount ppa = (PPAccount)o;
```

The stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectStreamClass
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at in.msitprogram.iiit.paypal.persistance.DataStore.lookupAccount(DataStore.java:50)
    at in.msitprogram.iiit.paypal.persistance.DataStore.writeAccount(DataStore.java:131)
    at in.msitprogram.iiit.paypal.console.PPNewAccountScreen.show(PPNewAccountScreen.java:78)
    at in.msitprogram.iiit.paypal.console.MainMenu.show(MainMenu.java:42)
    at in.msitprogram.iiit.paypal.PPSystem.main(PPSystem.java:17)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at in.msitprogram.iiit.paypal.persistance.DataStore.lookupAccount(DataStore.java:66)
    at in.msitprogram.iiit.paypal.persistance.DataStore.writeAccount(DataStore.java:131)
    at in.msitprogram.iiit.paypal.console.PPNewAccountScreen.show(PPNewAccountScreen.java:78)
    at in.msitprogram.iiit.paypal.console.MainMenu.show(MainMenu.java:42)
    at in.msitprogram.iiit.paypal.PPSystem.main(PPSystem.java:17)
```

The `lookUpAccount` reads from the stream while `writeAccount` writes to the stream, here is the code:

```
public static PPAccount lookupAccount(String email) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        PPAccount account = null; //initialize it after reading from file
        // write code to open the files, read
        PPAccount foundAccount=null;
        ObjectInputStream ois=null;
        FileInputStream fis=null;
        File ff = new File(PPConstants.AllAccountDetails);
        if(!ff.exists())
        {
            //System.out.println("Required file not found");
            return null;
        }
        try
        {
            fis=new FileInputStream(PPConstants.AllAccountDetails);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            while(fis.available()>0 && foundAccount==null)
            {
                //Object o=null;
                PPAccount ppa=null;
                try
                {
                    ppa = (PPAccount)ois.readObject();
                    if(ppa==null)
                        return null;
                    System.out.println(ppa);
                }

                catch(ClassCastException cce)
                {
                    System.out.println("Class cast exception "+cce.getCause());
                    cce.printStackTrace();  
                }
                if(email.equals(ppa.getEmail()))
                {
                    foundAccount=ppa;
                    break;
                }
                if(ppa instanceof PPBusinessAccount)
                {
                    PPBusinessAccount ppba = (PPBusinessAccount)ppa;
                    ArrayList<PPRestrictedAccount> alist=ppba.getAccountOperators();
                    if(alist==null)
                        continue;
                    Iterator<PPRestrictedAccount> it = alist.iterator();
                    while(it.hasNext())
                    {
                        PPRestrictedAccount ppr=(PPRestrictedAccount) it.next();
                        System.out.println(ppr);
                        if(email.equals(ppr.getEmail()))
                        {
                            foundAccount = ppr;
                            break;
                        }
                    }//iterators while loop
                }//if it is a businessAccount
            }//outer while  
        }//try
        finally
        {
            if(ois!=null)
                ois.close();
            if(fis!=null)
                fis.close();
        }   
        return foundAccount;
    }
    public static void writeAccount(PPAccount account,Boolean append) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, DuplicateAccountException
    {
        ObjectOutputStream oos=null;
        FileOutputStream fos=null;
        try
        {
            if(!append)
            {
                fos= new FileOutputStream(PPConstants.AllAccountDetails);
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                //System.out.println("Not Appending");
                oos.writeObject(account);
            }
            else
            {
                File ff = new File(PPConstants.AllAccountDetails);
                if(!ff.exists())
                {
                    System.out.println("Required file not found");
                    return;
                }
                PPAccount aa=lookupAccount(account.getEmail());
                if(aa!=null)
                    throw new DuplicateAccountException("An Account already exits with this email-ID");
                oos = new AppendingObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(PPConstants.AllAccountDetails,append));
                oos.writeObject(account);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if(oos!=null)
                oos.close();
            if(fos!=null)
                fos.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post exception trace as well? It also gives a clear clue of what is wrong...

Comment: Are you writing anything else to the stream? For example, with any method other than writeObject()?

Comment: @EJP No i am writing nothing else to the stream other that `writeObject()` that is the only method that writes any one of these classes.

Comment: Can you show the code that is writing the object and more context around the code that's reading it (i.e. how is `ois` created)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is that the previous poster who gave you an appendable `ObjectOutputStream` led you astray. An `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream` tries to store each object only once, and then later refer back to the object already stored. That is, in the stream you can end up with something like this if you have a bunch of objects of the same class:

```
CLASS_1_DESCRIPTION
OBJECT_1
REF_TO_CLASS_1
OBJECT_2
REF_TO_CLASS_1
OBJECT_3
...
```

When an `ObjectInputStream` is converting the stream back into a bunch of objects, it maintains a list of what things it's already deserialized. The error it's telling you is that it was trying to deserialize an object, read what should have been a reference to the description of the object's class, but when it looked up that reference in its internal table it saw a `String`. Quite naturally, it blew up.

I think the fix is as simple as this - in your `AppendableObjectOutputStream`, change this method:

```
  @Override
  protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
    // do not write a header, but reset the handle list
    reset();
  }
```

the `reset()` method in `ObjectOutputStream` inserts a marker into the stream saying "throw away all the state at this point". Then, when you read this back in with a `ObjectInputStream`, the input stream's idea of what's been deserialized will match what the output stream thought the state was when it deserialized the stuff in the first place.

(EDIT: Answer question from comments)

The only detrimental consequences of this that I can think of:

- The final file will be longer than it would have been if you'd written everything all to one `ObjectOutputStream`, especially if the same `Profile` object appears multiple times. Even if not, you'll repeat class descriptors in the stream, so lots of repetitions of {open `AppendableObjectOutputStream`, write one object, close stream} could bloat the file size a bit.
- Related to that, after you deserialize everything you may end up with multiple copies of what should have been the identical object. For example, suppose you write a bunch of things including some `PPRestrictedAccount` objects, then close the stream, open it as an `AppendableObjectOutputStream`, and write out a `PPBusinessAccount` that has in its `operators` list some of the `PPRestrictedAccount`s you wrote out earlier. When you read all that back in, the `PPRestrictedAccount`s you read initially won't be the same objects (that is, they won't be `==`) to the `PPRestrictedAccount`s that you find in the `PPBusinessAccount`'s `operators` list. They'll be instantiated separately. To avoid this, you'd need to de-duplicate them with a [`readResolve`](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17491.html) method. Everything that was written to a single `AppendableObjectOutputStream` instance will be connected correctly however. Depending on your application, this might not be something to worry about at all.

In terms of will-this-blow-up-or-not safety, this is as safe as any other use of java serialization; there isn't anything specific about your classes that makes it work. Just be aware that any object written in multiple separate openings of the output file will be deserialized as separate copies of the original object. (Absent any `readResolve` magic)

Comment: `Perfect` After all the time i spent fixing this, the solution is one line. Thanks. I Will accept the answer and bounty tomorrow. I am interested to know, if `throwing away the state at this point` is safe or not? The solution worked for me, fine. But applying this to a general case scenario. Would it make the solution safe in all scenarios??

Comment: Edited main post to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this....

`readObject()` **returns the** `objects` of **type** `Object`, so you need to **explicitly cast them into its original types...**

**Eg:**

`PPAccount pa = (PPAccount) readObject();`

Comment: that is the original code i had, to clarify where the exception is, i change it like this, the `readObject()` method is throwing the error. I can't understand why?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Have a look at the stack trace. In any case ClassCastException could only be thrown if there already was a typecast.

Comment: @EJP true.... but reading through the documentation of `readObject()` i doubt that there may be a few other cases this exception is thrown.. but i quite couldn't get what it meant and when it is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

No clear answer for you, but some thoughts and things to try:

- The stack trace includes `at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)`, which indicates the problem occurs while deserializing a class containing an `ArrayList`.  Narrow your problem down by commenting out the `private ArrayList<Transaction> transactions;`
- Do you have the same problem if you generate a single file *without* using your appender?  If so, create two forms of the same content: one with appender, one without.  Diffs?
- I do see one other reference to a similar problem, no solution.  Also uses the same appender: [Serialization/deserialization ClassCastException: x cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectStreamClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036603/serialization-deserialization-classcastexception-x-cannot-be-cast-to-java-io-ob)

Comment: I am facing no problems when using *without* the appender. And kindly note that i am also able to read and write into the stream, but only in specific order. If the first class to be written is of `PPBusinessAccount` everything seems to work fine. If the ArrayList is the culprit then it should fail in a different order too right? Anyways tested by removing the array list and also by making it null. The results weren't any different.

Comment: Ok, so let's leave the ArrayList out just to minimize noise for the moment.  Can you generate a file (a) "PBAccount, PBAccount, PBAccount, PBBusinessAccount" using the appender for each object after the first, and (b) without using the appender at all.  Run `diff` on the two files.