# How to implement this subclass specifically to get around appending object file?

Tags: java, objectoutputstream, object-files

I was having trouble appending object file in my program. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream/1195078#1195078) SO answer.

However, I do not know how to subclass an `AppendableObjectOutputStream`. Can anyone kindly teach me how in more detail?

Comment: AppendableObjectOutputStream is already a subclass of ObjectOutputStream. What you really need?

Comment: so you mean I can just use like
AppendableObjectOutputStream oos = 
 new AppendableObjectOutputStream(bout);
?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can create new instances of any class that is not marked as abstract. So you can copy/pase the code in your application and don't forget to implement the `writeStreamHeader` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YourClass extends AppendableObjectOutputStream {
// any constructors required, if no default for Appendable
    public AppendableObjectOutputStream(<your args here>) {
        super(<other args here>);
    }
// any methods you want to @Override here
}
```