# How to take a binary file, read it, convert it into usable data, and store it into an ArrayList

Tags: java, deserialization, binaryfiles

I am trying to get the binary data, "deserialize?" it into usable data from the file `statePopulationPercentages.dat`.

Then I want to add the integers to an `ArrayList<Integer>` called `percentages`, but for starters, just print them out.

I'm really new to java and working with binary files so any help would be great.  Here's what I've got so far.

```
    try {
        // Open the file for reading.
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("statePopulationPercentages.dat", "r");

        long position = raf.length();

        while (position > 0) {

            position -= 1;

            raf.seek(position);
            byte b = raf.readByte();

            // line = deserialize "b"

            // add to ArrayList<Integer> percentages
            // percentages.add(line);

            System.out.print((int) b); // this would obviously go away when adding to the array list
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You need to start by specifying the file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file was created by serializing Java objects, this is a page that has info on deserializing the objects into an `ArrayList`:

[Deserialize multiple Java Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145682/deserialize-multiple-java-objects)