# Reading an object file written by ObjectOutputStream in append mode (multiple closings)

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have written multiple objects in the same file over last 2 weeks. Each time (probably million times) I called:

```
try(ObjectOutputStream output=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("somefile"),true))) {            
        output.writeObject(someobject);               
        output.close();
    }
```

Now when I try to read it using:

```
try(ObjectInputStream input=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("somefile")))) {   
        while(true) {     
            PROCESS_IT(input.readObject());
        }
    }
```

It reads only first object and gives error:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1379)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
```

I know now that I should have overridden the streamheader while writing these objects ([Appending to an ObjectOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream?rq=1))

But it took me *two weeks* already to get the results in this "somefile". **Can I somehow still read all the objects by skipping the corrupt bytes/headers?** 
Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not (yet) tested it, but you should be able to recreate the ObjectInputStream each time on the same FileInputStream and it wil re-read the header.

For example (again, untested) :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("someFile");
while (true) {
  ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(fis)
  try {
    PROCESS_IT(input.readObject());
  }
  // Don't close the DataInputStream, it would close the underlying FileInputStream
}
```

The theory should be that when you create the ObjectInputStream, it will read the header, and then read an object, advancing the underlying FileInputStream. Then, when you iterate and create a second ObjectInputStream, it has no knowledge that the underlying FileInputStream was already partially consumed, so will re-read the header and read another object. And so on.

Comment: I tested. But still it reads only first object and gives "   java.io.IOException: Stream Closed" error few times.

Comment: You might have to not close the `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: No.  That definitely won't work.  The `try` will close `input` which will close `fis`.

Comment: Yes, now I tried without using "try" statement and seems to be working. Thanks a tons. Saved me from extra hassle.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot the try->close->close thing, that's why I specified the code was untested but only to give an idea of how it could work. Now modified the answer to specify that the ObjectInputStream must not be closed.