# Serialization: Appending to Object Files in Java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, file-handling, persistent-storage

I recently made a serial file for the users. Which I read from when a user tries to log in. And add users to it if a new user registers. But whenever I add a new user the previous record that I added is deleted. Is there a way to append objects to serial files?
P.S Im using objects of users which contain username, password, role (instructor or student) and a score (int) variable.

```
public static void addRecordStudent(String userName, String password, String role, int score)
{
    openFile();
    try
    {
        // create new record; this example assumes valid input
        User usr = new User(userName, password, role, score);
        // serialize record object into file
        output.writeObject(usr);
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException elementException)
    {
        System.err.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
    }
    catch (IOException ioException)
    {
        System.err.println("Error writing to file. Terminating.");
    }
    closeFile();
}

 public static void openFile()
{
    try
    {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("users.ser")));
    }
    catch (IOException ioException)
    {
        System.err.println("Error opening file. Terminating.");
        System.exit(1); // terminate the program
    }
}

public static void closeFile()
{
    try
    {
        if (output != null)
        output.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioException)
    {
        System.err.println("Error closing file. Terminating.");
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code also

Comment: you need to post it as part of your question not as a comment

Comment: done, new to the site.

Comment: what is openFile methed ?

Comment: both methods added to code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195078/2299040

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly choose to append to file - otherwise old content will be replaced:

[Files.newOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...))(file, [StandardOpenOption.APPEND](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#APPEND))

In addition to that, every time you create new ObjectOutputStream new stream is started. You won't be able to read them back using single ObjectInputStream. You can avoid that using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream)

If the file is not too large, it might be a better idea to read all existing objects and then write back existing and new objects using single ObjectOutputStream.