# Appending to a file with ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, oop

i have this simple method that writes to a file:

```
    File f = new File(address);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(s);
```

how do i append to the file instead of losing old contents every time i run it.

Thanks,

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(f, true)`

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream) is a trick for ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: @lexicore No. That doesn't work. There is far more to it.