# How to appends objects in byte stream using ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

I want to append multiple object at the end to the same binary file using ObjectOutputStream 
But when I run the following code more than one time I get the exception

`java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC`

The question is 
Is there any headers things that I should know to APPEND OBJECTS at the end of the file in java?

```
package sourcepackage;

import sourcepackage.persons.Person;
import sourcepackage.persons.Student;

import java.io.*;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person mahmoud_kanbar = new Student(21, 224466, "Mahmoud Kanbar", "ITE");


        try {

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Hello.dat", true);

            ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

            objectOut.writeObject(mahmoud_kanbar);

            objectOut.close();
            out.close();

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("Hello.dat");

            ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);


            while (in.available() != 0) {
                Person hi = (Person) objectIn.readObject();
                hi.printInfo();
            }

            objectIn.close();
            in.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);

        }


    }
}
```

I was searching for decades about a solution to this problem and I couldn't find anything 
I want to append objects just like the c++ do

Comment: The answer to my question is in a previous post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195078/10461503)

Answer (score 0):

You can append objects to the same `ObjectOutputStream` with `writeObject()` method. When reading, they are read in the same order they were written. Also, you may be getting that error because your stream is buffered and not written. You should use `flush()` method to make sure the buffer has been written to the file. 
Let's write two objects to the same file and read them:

```
Person mahmoud_kanbar = new Student(21, 224466, "Mahmoud Kanbar", "ITE");
Person omid = new Student(18, 200000, "Omid Nejadabbasi", "ITE");

try {

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Hello.dat", true);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        objectOut.writeObject(mahmoud_kanbar);
        objectOut.writeObject(omid);
        objectOut.flush();
        objectOut.close();
        out.close();

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("Hello.dat");

        ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);


        Person newPerson= (Person)  objectIn.readObject();
        newPerson.printInfo();
        newPerson= (Person)  objectIn.readObject();
        newPerson.printInfo();

        objectIn.close();
        in.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);

    }
```

`readObject()` deserializes the next Object serialized into the stream.

Comment: That doesn't work, I want to append the next time I open the program